# How to avoid reshape/reshape2 melt.data.frame conflicts in R package

Tags: r, reshape2

I use `melt.data.frame` from the `reshape2` in a package. For reasons I cannot control, I've had users load my package (which imports `reshape2`)...then load the `reshape` package, causing future errors from my package (an official Warning...and incorrect output for my code).

I've seen this discussion:
[Reshape package masking preventing melt from naming columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896632/reshape-package-masking-preventing-melt-from-naming-columns)

So I know I can use `reshape2:::melt.data.frame` to prevent the conflict, but that generates a Note on check that I'd rather avoid. The `gather` function in `tidyr` doesn't solve it either. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(x=rep("a",4),
                 y=c(1:3,NA),
                 key=c("g","g","c","d"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

melt(df,id.vars = "key")

library(reshape)
melt(df,id.vars = "key")
reshape2::melt(df,id.vars = "key")
reshape2:::melt.data.frame(df,id.vars = "key") #No problem
reshape2::melt(df, measure.vars =  c("x","y"), 
               variable.name = "variable", 
               value.name = "value", na.rm = FALSE)

library(tidyr)
gather(df, variable, value, -key)
gather_(df, "variable", "value", c("x","y"))
```